# How to set the input of a combobox to read-only

Tags: sapui5

In one of my UI5-Dialogs, I implemented a combobox which is invisible when the screen is initially loaded.
In the method `onAfterRendering`, I start with setting the input to read-only:

```js
onAfterRendering: function(oEvent) {
  var oShovel = this.getView("View0200").byId("comboShovel");
  oShovel.$().find("input").attr("readonly", true);
  this.setVisibleByListKey();
},
```

After this the method `setVisibleByListKey` is called, the property `visibleShovel` will be set to false.

```js
setVisibleByListKey: function(oEvent) {
  var oModel = this.getView("View0200").getModel("Data0200");
  this.setVisibleByListKey1(oModel);
  // ...
},

setVisibleByListKey1: function(oModel) {
  oModel.setProperty("/visibleShovel", false);
},
```

The property is bound to the attribute visible on my combobox.
Because of this behavior, the method `onAfterRendering` will be called again, the attribute `readonly` is not available (because of invisibility).

```xml
<ComboBox id="comboShovel"
  editable="true"
  enabled="true"
  visible="{Data0200>/visibleShovel}"
  valueState="None"
  change=".changeCombo">
  <items>
    <core:Item text="Ja" enabled="true" key="0" />
    <core:Item text="Nein" enabled="true" key="1" />
    <core:Item text="Nicht erforderlich" enabled="true" key="2" />
  </items>
</ComboBox>
```

I tried to call the set method in `onInit` or `onBeforeRendering` but at this time the input attributes can not be changed (because of invisibility again).

So how can I set the input of the combobox to read-only when I set the named visible property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution would be either to use `sap.m.Select` or to implement a "change" event handler for the `sap.m.Combobox` and use a coding similar to [this sample](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.ComboBox/sample/sap.m.sample.ComboBoxValidation/code/Page.controller.js):

> ```js
> handleChange: function(oEvent) {
>   var oValidatedComboBox = oEvent.getSource();
>   var sSelectedKey = oValidatedComboBox.getSelectedKey();
>   var sValue = oValidatedComboBox.getValue();
>   if (!sSelectedKey && sValue) {
>     oValidatedComboBox.setValueState("Error");
>     oValidatedComboBox.setValueStateText("Please enter a valid country!");
>   } else {
>     oValidatedComboBox.setValueState("None");
>   }
> },
> ```

Comment: `sap.m.Select` is the perfect replacement for a ComboBox without the abililty to edit the selection value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jquery, use UI5 control's methods and properties:

The [sap.m.ComboBox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ComboBox) borrows the following two methods from [sap.m.InputBase](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase):

[setEditable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/methods/setEditable)

[setEnabled](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/methods/setEnabled)

or since you are using property binding for the visibility, do the same for the editable property, e.g. `{Data0200>/editableShovel}`

Comment: The problem is, if i use setEditable or setEnabled i sadly cant choose the items of the checkbox.

Comment: Because im fairly new to SAPUI5 programming and i wanted to know if i unterstand something wrong here and on top of that i didnt need to check the Input afterwards

Comment: @cf.codings Isn't then [`sap.m.Select`](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/select/) what you're looking for? The Select control is "read only" but still allows users to select an item. But if there are only three options anyway, [`sap.m.RadioButton(Group)`](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/radio-button/) or [`.SegmentedButton`](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/button/#segmented-buttons) would be more preferred in terms of UX. Or would you like to stick with ComboBox? What are you trying to understand?

Comment: @boghyonHoffmann I tried to understand if its possible with the comobox, but the sap.m.select is a good alternative solution. I will stick to the combobox for now, because i implemented a reaction to the event change, to verify the input.